# Assign value to an array object in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am attempting to assign a value to an array object like this:

```
public class Players {
    String Name;
}

Players[] player = new Players[10];
String name = Mike;
player[1].Name = name;
```

I am getting a NullPointerException and am not sure why. What could be causing this?

Comment: This class should really be named `Player`, since each instance is only one player..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think will change the class to player and the array to players

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because creating a new array does not create individual objects inside the array; you should be creating them separately, e.g. in a loop.

```
Players[] player = new Players[10];
for (int i = 0 ; i != player.length ; i++) {
    player[i] = new Players();
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying in concept but not implementation. Could you please give an example?

Comment: Wow thank you. I didn't realize the objects were not created by initializing the array

Answer (score 4):

`new Players[10]` makes an array with 10 slots.  It doesn't put anything in the slots.  So all 10 elements of the array are `null`.

You need to create the objects and stick them into the array.  For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < player.length; i++) {
    player[i] = new Players();
}
```